# Oracle database dependencies in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to find dependencies between functions/procedures(defined inside package bodies) and tables which they use.

I've tried `all_dependencies` but it works only on the package-level, not the inner function/procedure-level. 
Is there any possibilty to find this dependencies using e.g. `all_source`?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: try out `dba_dependencies` like `select * from dba_dependencies where name = 'YOUR_OBJECT'`

Comment: It really doesn't help if I use dba_dependencies instead of all_dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to find the dependencies between procedures (in a package) and tables.

There are several tools to examine dependencies.  As you've already discovered, `*_DEPENDENCIES` only tracks object dependencies on a per-package level.  There is a neat tool [PL/Scope](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_plscope.htm#ADFNS022) that tracks dependencies between parts of a package.  But it does it does not track all table references.

Theoretically you could use `*_SOURCE`.  In practice, this is impossible unless your code uses a limited set of features.  For any moderately complicated code, forget about using string functions or [regular expressions to parse code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/409172).  Unfortunately there does not seem to be any PL/SQL parser that is both programmable and capable of accurately parsing complex code.

Saying "it's not possible" isn't a great answer.  But in this case it might save you a lot of time.  This is one of those tasks where it's very easy to hit a dead end and waste a lot of effort.

Comment: Thanks for this brutal clarification :)